# Listview Element onItemClickListeners overlapping

Tags: android, listview

I've created a list view that automatically created its content from an sql DB. When clicked, each list item opens into another page based on what was clicked, but the area for clicking on each member of the list seems to extend across the entire page, despite each member only filling part of the page, as a result the click areas overlap.

In this example, the red represents where the click area should be for the first list member, and the purple represents where it actually is. The same is happening with all the other members, the highest one up just appears to take precedence.

[image]

The list members are created from

> panel_stream.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:elevation="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/panel_header_shape"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Update Title Here"
        android:id="@+id/panelTitle"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:textColor="#eeeeee"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Unattributed"
        android:id="@+id/panelAuthor"
        android:textColor="#dddddd"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#111111"
        android:background="@drawable/panel_shape"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/panelContent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Content" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/panel_footer_shape"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="0"
        android:id="@+id/commentCount"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_comment_black_24dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:contentDescription="comment" />-->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="2016-04-20 04:20:00"
        android:id="@+id/dateStamp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/panelID"
        android:textColor="#00FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:maxLines="1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And are placed in the ListView inside >activity_board_stream_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.company.panels.BoardView"
android:background="@color/background"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPanel"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titleFrame" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sorting By"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#222222"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sortBy"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

</RelativeLayout>

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/panelHost"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:divider="#00FFFFFF" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="End of Content"
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" />
```

Here is the onItemClickListener

> BoardView.java:

```
package com.company.panels;
//Imports and irrelevant methods excluded


public class BoardView extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mydb = new DBManager(this);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.board_stream_menu, menu);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_board_stream_view);

    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.panelHost);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            TextView dateStamp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.panelID) ;
            toViewPanel(dateStamp.getText().toString());
        }});
    return true;
}}
```

Comment: Post screen shot too.

Comment: I just added one for clarity

Comment: Please post your `OnItemClickListener`, and the `getView()` method of your `Adapter`, if you're using a custom one.

Comment: I just added it in

Comment: Your problem is the `findViewById()` call. That method will search the `Activity` for the first `View` it finds with that ID. Your `ListView` will have several with the same ID, but the first one - i.e., the top one - will be returned. You should instead get the necessary info from the dataset you're passing to the `Adapter`.

Comment: How/ where would I implement that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `OnItemClickListener` instead of `OnClickListener` for `ListView`.
(More info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)

Comment: I am using onItemClickListener, I just forgot to clarify that

Comment: Could you post the onItemClickListener code as well?

Comment: I just added it in

Comment: In `ListView`, you have to specify which view of `(TextView)findViewById(R.id.panelID) ;` you want to get, otherwise you'll get the top one.

Comment: How do I specify to select the one I clicked on?

Comment: U can use view.findViewById(), there is a view parameter inside onitemclicklistener.

Comment: That fixed the problem, Thanks!